# Cannot get the last row of data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, row

In my ASP.NET application, i need to read the CSV file and insert into sql server.

and it was strange that it treat the 1st row (`column name`) as `LineNumber=2`.

but i found that my code cannot read the last row of the CSV file.

```
    Dim CSV_content As String = ""
    Dim CSVFilePathName As String = Server.MapPath("~/XXX/" & filename)

    If File.Exists(CSVFilePathName) = True Then
        'Response.Write("exists")

        Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(CSVFilePathName)
        Dim CurrentRecord As String()
        afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        Dim LastName As String = ""
        Dim FirstName As String = ""
        Dim DisplayName As String = ""
        Dim EmailName As String = ""

        Dim dc As New dcHRISDataContext

        ' parse the actual file
        Do While Not afile.EndOfData

            Try

CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields

                'insert into tmp db
                If afile.LineNumber > 2 Then

                    Dim newRecord1 As New XXX
                    dc.XXX.InsertOnSubmit(newRecord1)

                    newRecord1.LastName = CurrentRecord(0).Trim
                    newRecord1.FirstName = CurrentRecord(1).Trim
                    newRecord1.DisplayName = CurrentRecord(1).Trim
                    newRecord1.DirEmail = CurrentRecord(3).Trim
                    newRecord1.GetFileDate = DateTime.Now
                    newRecord1.GetFileName = filename
                    dc.SubmitChanges()
                End If

                                Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
                Stop
            End Try
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: CurrentRecord is never set. Have you removed it by mistake while trying to make this more readable?

Comment: sorry for  copy & paste mistake...  had added "CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields" to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is the dumbest issue that I have seen.

Anyhow, Apparently the last row in the TextFieldParser is -1, and not LastRowWithValuesIndex + 1. So what happens is this.

1. You read the data of the last line (this is fine)
2. The reader skips to the next line to prepare the next line to read (this is fine)
3. You get the afile.LineNumber, now set to the next line. Which is -1
   at this point. (this is dumb although understandable, not your fault)
4. Your if statement wont let you in because hey you are on line -1.
5. Loop ends, skipping last row in the CSV.

All you have to do is to read the line number of the row before reading the data:

```
Dim i As Integer = afile.LineNumber
CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
If i > 2 Then
etc
```